# Decomposing the homology of a connected sum of surfaces in a way which highlights the combinatorics of gluing

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

For each $i = 1,2$ and $j = 1,\ldots,n$, let $C_{i,j}$ be a connected compact oriented surface with $k$ boundary components. For $i = 1,2$, let $C_i = \sqcup_{j=1}^n C_{i,j}$, and let $C$ be the closed orientable surface obtained by attaching cylinders connecting boundary components of $C_1$ to those of $C_2$.

I would like to decompose $H_1(C)$ as a direct sum of $A_1,A_2,B$, where $A_1,A_2$ are related to $H_1(C_1),H_1(C_2)$, and $B$ is related to the combinatorics of how the various components of $C_1,C_2$ are glued together. If $\Gamma$ denotes the component graph of $C$ (it has $2n$ vertices corresponding to the components $C_{i,j}$ and $nk$ edges corresponding to the cylinders), then $h_1(\Gamma) = nk-2n+1$. Mayer-Vietoris shows that
$$h_1(C) = h_1(C_1) + h_1(C_2) - 2n + 2$$
Thus if $\overline{C_1},\overline{C_2}$ denote the closed surfaces obtained by "capping" the boundary holes, then $h_1(C_i) = h_1(\overline{C_i}) + nk - n$. Thus we have
$$h_1(C) = h_1(\overline{C_1}) + h_1(\overline{C_2}) + 2(nk-2n+1) = h_1(\overline{C_1}) + h_1(\overline{C_2}) + 2h_1(\Gamma)$$
This "decomposition" of Betti numbers is helpful because it indicates that the homology of the glued surface $C$ comes from cycles in $\overline{C_1}$ and $\overline{C_2}$, together with the $h_1(\Gamma)$-many cycles coming from loops in the component graph, together with another $h_1(\Gamma)$-many cycles which come from "loops around the cylinders". In fact I want to think of the contribution of $2h_1(\Gamma)$ as somehow identifying the associated homology classes in $H_1(C)$ with the homology of the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $\Gamma$ embedded in 3-space. Let $\partial N_\Gamma$ denote this boundary. This space records the combinatorics of the gluing data.

I'd like some way of making this precise. While Mayer-Vietoris gives a decomposition of the number $h_1(C)$ into a sum of things that are of the desired form "$A_1$", "$A_2$", "$B$", I would like to construct natural maps between the homology groups that realize this. In other words, I'd like to define in a natural way an isomorphism
$$H_1(\overline{C_1})\oplus H_1(\overline{C_2})\oplus H_1(\partial N_\Gamma)\stackrel{\cong}{\longrightarrow} H_1(C)$$

I'm sure this must be discussed somewhere in the literature, so references would also be appreciated!